# Is Core Data model relationship correct based on image?

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, core-data, ios7

An `Order` can contain many `OrderLines` - items purchased associated to that order.

I want to be able to select all orders along with their associated orderlines when the user wants to see the `Order history view controller` in my application.

I have this setup atm, is this correct? please note the right information pane so you can see the setup for that relationship property.

[image]

**Question 1.**
Is my relationship correct for me to be able to retrieve all orderlines when selecting orders or do I need to perform two queries, one to retrieve all the `orders` and the other to retrieve all `orderLines` and then combine them based on which `orderLines` has which `order` associated to it. That's what Im doing in my SQL setup at the backend, but Im hoping core data can grab rows in a much better fasion.

**Question 2.** the user should be able to delete any `OrderLine` without it affecting the `Orders` entity except for updating the `Order's`orderTotalAmount`property. But my question being, I dont want an`Order`to be deleted when I delete a specific`orderLine`. For that would I need to set the delete rule to`No Action`?

**Question 3.** Is my relationship fine if I want to have it so that 1 `order` can have many `OrderLines` associated to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Apple recommendation you should setup inverse relationship as well.

Orders to OrederLines is to-many and OrderLines to Orders you have setup correctly - it shouldn't be optional however.
For Orders you should also have Delete Rule: Cascade - so if you delete Orders it will delete all related OrderLines

1. CoreData will do that for you - what's more it will do it in lazy mode - only when you access relationship objects they will be loaded. You can change that and preload all, but it's only when you really need that.
2. You should leave nullify action for that - it will correctly update Orders and disconnect related objects when they are deleted.
3. Asnwered at beggining - you should have also inverse relation from Orders to OrderLines as to-many. This will also generate for you methods you should use to auto-create relations.

   ```
   - (void) addOrderLinesObject:(OrderLines*)value;
   - (void) removeOrderLinesObject:(OrderLines*)value;
   ```

When you setup it correctly you will have also in Order class:

```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* orderLines;
```

With that you can access related objects.

Comment: Could you have a look at my 3 folded question pls and explain how your answer aims to answer those questions. Thank you dude

Comment: Thanks for that. in relation to what you said in point 2, in what way will the orders be "updated"?

Comment: Yes - this is why you should setup inverse relationship, so SQLLite can setup link back to orders and optimize it, so when you detete OrderLines they have reference to Contact and can remove themselfes from Order.

Comment: in relation to point 3, no way :O ?! I never knew automatic methods like those would be created! That's awesome and will come very helpful!

Comment: So whats the difference in having set to `no action` instead of `nullify`? All I want is that when I delete an orderline, that it shouldn't go around deleting any orders, since that order associated to the deleted orderline could still have other orderlines associated to that order. I dont want null objects lying around, otherwise I then have to check for null to.

Comment: I believe it will be `OrderLines *orderLines`, once I have all the automatic class objects generated for me.

Comment: If your Order can have multiple OrderLines it will be NSSet and you should only  use generated method for connecting those objects.

Comment: Ah right, I see what you mean, because its a one to many relationship of OrderLines. If you could just answer my previous comment about difference between no action and nullify then I believe everything will have been made clear to me!

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdRelationships.html. No acton - Do nothing to the object at the destination of the relationship. That typically shouldn't be used because if you delete one of OrderLines objects connected Order will still keep a refernce to object you just deleted. So in that can nullify will properly update Order so it loses reference to an object which you are deleting. With no-action approach you have to take care of that manually and assign new related object for Order it can lead to consistency errors

Comment: +1 for a fantastic answer. Thank you @grzegorz. Nullify will be the best choice then.

Comment: Oh 1 more thing - your relation from OrderLines to Order shouldn't be optional. That will prevent from bugs if someone will try to create OrderLines without Order relationship - the exception will be raised. Probably worth setting just to be 100% correct ;)

Comment: Aha, yes thats right, when i had taken the screenshot I was too lazy to uncheck and retake the screenshot, and also was lazy to inclide a sentence to ignore that optional tickmark! But thanks for that, it will be helpful to others that read it!

Comment: Just a quick one, I know it's off topic, in your experience, if you want to store the price of something, should that be stored as a decimal, float or double?

Comment: float gives you enough precision and it is smaller than others. double is not required just for 2 numbers after ",", probably you just need prize in format %2.2f (for example 10.55).

Comment: Precision for basic types:
Float - 7 digits (32 bit)
Double-15-16 digits (64 bit)
Decimal -28-29 significant digits (128 bit). You should always choose the smallest one meeting your required precision :)

Comment: *cough* quickly goes back to change all my datamodel's properties from decimal to float because 10.55 is exactly how I need it! aha! Got it, always use smallest data type that meets the required precision. Thank you Grzegorz!